# What is the difference between `myClass obj(var1, var2)` and `myClass obj= myClass(var1, var2)`

Tags: c++, class

If `myClass` is a class, what's the difference between defining `obj` as `myClass obj(var1, var2)` and defining it as `myClass obj = myClass(var1, var2)`?

Comment: In C++11 or later: a usually-elided move. In C++98, it was a usually-elided *copy*, which caused problems since moves didn't exist yet.

Comment: @o11c: Why did it cause problems if it was usually elided?

Comment: Certainly a valid question.  I suspect there's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: @KerrekSB Because the copy-ctor had to *exist*, even if it ended up not being called. Move-only types are very convenient.

Comment: @o11c There were no move-only types in C++98, so no problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza Incorrect, there was simply no *language* support for them. The library-level implementation does not work in this case, which is the problem.

Comment: @o11c That really makes no sense.

Comment: @juanchopanza the `.swap(T&)` member functions were the most common library-level move implementations, but it's also possible to use e.g. a template class.

Comment: In C++17, I believe there's no difference between these, barring any most vexing parse differences you might run into more generally.

Comment: I feel that the "duplicate" is too broad; in general there are a lot of differences between copy initialization and direct initialization;  but not for OP's specific case (initialization from expression  of the same type).